# Motd messages to display current events in the world

Tags: linux, motd

I need to know if it's possible to setup dynamic motd messages on Linux servers which should display the snippets of current events happening in the world when someone login. If its possible please do let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

motd is in `/etc/motd`. Feel free to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `pam_motd`.

Basically, you only have to create `/etc/update-motd.d` and put scripts into that directory of the form 00scriptname (no extension).

The output of those scripts will be presented upon login, and the scripts can generate dynamic content

You can follow this guide

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/04/05/customize-your-motd-login-message-in-debian-and-ubuntu/